# Why choosing $x$ at random from $Z_N^*$ is equivalent to choosing $x_j$ s.t. $x = x_j \pmod{p_j^{\alpha_j}}$ with $p_j^{\alpha_j}$ a factor of $N$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, coprime

On the book "Quantum computation and quantum information" from Nielsen and Chuang on page 634 at the beginning of a theorem's proof it's assumed to be able to choose a number $x$ uniformly at random from $Z_N^*$ with $N = p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_m^{\alpha_m}$ and $p_j$ a prime factor.

However the book says that this operation is equivalent to choosing $x_j$ independently and uniformly at random from $Z_{p_j^{\alpha_j}}^*$ and requiring that $x = x_j\pmod{p_j^{\alpha_j}}$ for each $j$.

I understood that this system has a solution thanks to the Chinese remainder theorem but
how is the solution $x$ co-prime to $N$?

Comment: If $\gcd(x,N)\neq1$ then $p_j\mid x$ for some $j$, and then $p_j\mid x_j$.

Comment: SInce $x$ is coprime to each ${p_i}^\alpha_i$ it it coprime to their product, by the linked dupe.